Zero sets of distinct primes distinct?
Let K be a field of infinite size and let $F_1,F_2 \in K[X_1,...,X_n]$ where $n \geq 2$. For $F \in K[X_1,..,X_n] $ define $V_K(F) = \{ a \in K^n | F(a) = 0 \}$. Suppose $F_1,F_2$ are distinct primes and we are given that $V_K(F_1)$ and $V_K(F_2)$ are infinite sets. Can we say $V_K(F_1) \neq V_K(F_2)$?
Context: I was reading a textbook on introduction to commutative algebra and algebraic geometry, and they said that the defining polynomial of an algebraic curve (with some constraints) is unique up to constants. No proof was provided, and in trying to prove that statement, I wanted to prove this simpler version. I tried going to $Alg-closure(K(x_1,....,x_{n-1}))$ to get some insights but was not making any progress.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

If $K$ is algebraically closed, we can use Hilbert's Nullstelensatz. If $V_K(F_1) = V_K(F_2)$, then $(F_1) = \sqrt{(F_1)} = \sqrt{(F_2)} = (F_2)$ so $F_1 = F_2$ modulo $K^*$. Notice that it is enough to get this result to assume that for each $i$, $(F_i) = \sqrt{(F_i)}$ i.e. $F_i$ is square-free.
If $K$ is not algebraically closed, it is false. Consider for example $K = \mathbb{R}$ and $n \geqslant 3$. Set $F_1 = X_1^2 + X_2^2$ and $F_2 = X_1^2 + 2X_2^2$. They have the same vanishing locus $\{x_1 = x_2 = 0\}$ (it is infinite because $n \geqslant 3$) despite they are not proportional. If you want the result to be true, I believe it is enough to assume that the vanishing loci of the $F_i$ are hypersurfaces (it is stronger than being infinite, except if $n = 2$, it is equivalent), or equivalently, that there exists an $a \in V_K(F_i)$ such that $dF_i(a) \neq 0$.
Edit : if $K$ is any field and $n = 2$, we have for each $i$, $V_K(F_i) = V_{\overline{K}}(F_i) \cap K^2$ where $\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$. These sets are infinite so are their Zariski closures $\overline{V_K(F_i)} \subset \overline{K}^2$. We deduce that theire dimension is greater than or equal to $1$. Using $\overline{V_K(F_i)} \subset \overline{V_{\overline{K}}(F_i)} = V_{\overline{K}}(F_i)$ and $\dim(\overline{V_K(F_i)}) \geqslant 1 = V_{\overline{K}}(F_i)$, we have $\overline{V_K(F_i)} = V_{\overline{K}}(F_i)$. Therefore,
$$
V_{\overline{K}}(F_1) = \overline{V_K(F_1)} = \overline{V_K(F_2)} = V_{\overline{K}}(F_2).
$$
Since $\overline{K}$ is algebraically closed, we have $F_1 = F_2$ modulo $\overline{K}^*$ and since they have coefficients in $K$, $F_1 = F_2$ modulo $K^*$.

Thanks for the answer ! The case in the book I was reading was $n =2$. If possible can you expand your answer on the case $n=2$

I added the case $n = 2$.
